# Is there a way to use some sort of "instancing" when storing polygons in a spatial database?

Tags: postgis, polygon, postgis-2.0

I am quite new to GIS database addons, and I am still exploring the possible uses for them. In general the idea of storing objects indexed by their position which enables additional operations is pretty cool.

However, it's fit for data gathered from real world scenarios, where every park, building etc. will have its own set of points. The simplest way is to simply store them as points and execute regular queries on them.

However, imagine we're putting some imaginary objects on the map, belonging to a few categories, but in large quantities. Let's take a star shape for example. Now, I can simply add the set of polygons every time I want to place my star in my "world", but this creates a huge duplication of data and requires me to modify each and every record shall I want to update the shape somehow.

The obvious solution to that is to store only the position of said shape, and a key to some other table holding shapes with 0-based coordinates. I can perform things like intersection tests by using `ST_Translate` on the shape and its position; so far so good.

Will this approach scale to a bigger number of instances? Will I be able to perform every query I would be able to using regular polygon storage?

And lastly, but not leastly, doesn't PostGIS provide a built-in support for that? I was unable to find that in the documentation.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of spatial analysis or map design? For the latter, simple points and symbol styles should suffice. Otherwise, I don't know and you're unlikely to find a solution for ArcGIS.

Comment: @Eyrofire It's for a completely different purpose. And I'm not using ArcGIS, I don't know why you've mentioned it at all.

Comment: Sorry misread PostGIS as ArcGIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, presumably you're thinking about a "locations" table and a "shapes" table, with a N:1 relationship between them. The only thing that might be tricky is the spatial indexing. (Fix syntax errors below)

```
CREATE TABLE location (
  location_id serial primary key, 
  shape_id integer references shapes(shape_id),
  bounds geometry,
  x_off double,  
  y_off double
);

CREATE TABLE shape (
  shape_id serial primary key, 
  geom geometry
);
```

I think the only tricky thing would be the bounds. In order to get a spatial index, you'll have to keep the bounds in the location table, but at least then you're only storing 4 points per location, not N points. You'll need a trigger on update for the shape table to update the bounds of all related records. But then a containment query would look like

```
SELECT location_id
FROM location JOIN shape USING (shape_id)
WHERE ST_Intersects(location.bounds, $pt)
AND ST_Contains(ST_Translate(shape.geom, location.x_off, location.y_off), $pt)
```

Comment: So that shouldn't have that dramatic performance impact? Superb. Thanks for the tip with the bounds, too.

Comment: CREATE INDEX location_bounds_gix ON location USING GIST (bounds);